# How do you downsample an image in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: photoshop, image-quality, rescaling

I've tried reducing size but the quality is greatly reduced as well, not to mention custom pixel ratios will make it look ridiculous. What should i do?

EDIT: I have used a 1936 X 2592 JPEG picutre and wanted it to be 1280x 800 JPEG picture. I resized by using Image>Image Size and then changed the numbers.

Comment: Can you supply some more detail?  Original resolution, target resolution, which method did you choose for the re-sizing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't just downsizing your image, you're wanting to change the aspect ratio from 4:3 to 8:5, and if you've listed the dimensions consistently, you want to scale a portrait orientation image to  landscape as well.

Neither of those things is going to work without cropping your image.  Or adding to the image by adding a border or using something like content aware fill.

Hard to tell without looking at the image, but I'd start by setting the crop tool to dimensions of 1280 x 800 and see if you can crop something you like.  Then do the image resize.